# Django dependent dropdown with ajax. Do I need to divide my model to 3 different models in order to implement dependant dropdown?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-models

I have model in my django that describe cars. It have fields:

- make
- model
- price

I want to let users to create queries for them through django forms and I wanted to implement dependent dropdown. When user selects "make" then available "models" change.

I saw some tutorials but it seems that all of them would divide my model car into three different models but foreign keys. I suppose it would look something like this:

```
Makes:
- name

Models:
- make (foreign key)
- name

Car:
- price
- make (foreign key)
- model (foreign key)
```

I am wondering, is it possible to somehow implement this dependant dropdown in django forms while keeping only 1 cars model? And if so, what should I google?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @ChoopMiklon Hi, I added answer to my question. I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do that by making small edits to a solution from this link:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

In my case, ajax call in template looked like this:

```
{#Ajax call for loading up models based on selected make.#}
            <script>
                $("#id_make").change(function () {
                    const url = $("#SearchForm").attr("data-models-url");
                    const makeId = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            'make': makeId
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#id_model").html(data);
                        }
                    });

                });
            </script>
```

urls.py:

```
# Ajax:
path('ajax/load_models/', templates_views.load_models, name='ajax_load_models'),
```

ajax in views:

```
# This view is for AJAX call.
def load_models(request):
    make = request.GET.get('make')
    models = Car.objects.filter(make=make).values('model').annotate(count=Count('make')).order_by('count').distinct().reverse()
    models_count = []
    for model in models:
        models_count.append(Car.objects.filter(model=model['model']).count())

    data = zip(models, models_count)

    return render(request, 'car_prices_tool/models_dropdown_list_options.html', {'data': data})
```

models_dropdown_list_options.html:

```
<option value="">--- choose model ---</option>
{% for model, count in data %}
    <option value="{{ model.model }}">{{ model.model }} ({{ count }})</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I believe that is all, thanks to that I didn't have to create more models. I could use only one.